# PHP Login System ~ session.register and session.start errors (updated)

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have now changed my login system from session_register() to this:

**UPDATE**:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="david_bpd"; // Mysql username 
$password="documents123456"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="david_bpd"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=Login_success">';
}
elseif($count==0) {
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=Login_Unsuccessful">';
}
```

and I am now using session_start() to make sure the user is logged in:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
if ($_SESSION['myusername'] == $myusername) {
//User should be allowed to be on page
} else {
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=index">';
} 

} else {
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=index">';
}
?>
```

But even when i log in using the right credentials and register my username it still redirects me as if i was not logged in?

**Code for submitting form**

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"     bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form action="/?module=admin&n=checklogin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"     name="form1" id="form1">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Administrator Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input type="text" name="myusername" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td> <button type="submit" name="Submit">Login</button>
<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16" style="display: none"/>
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("img").show("slow");
});
</script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas,

Thanks

Comment: where is $myusername defined in the second php page?

Comment: Add some output before the checks so you do actually know if the login proceeded or not. Not that you look in the wrong place.

Comment: what do you get with var_dump($_SESSION)? Also, why not use PHP to do the redirect?

Comment: because the headers are already set in an index.php file and if i try to use header() it doesn;'t work and i know that it proceeds because it redirects me to login success and then immediately redirects me back

Comment: did you call session_start() before setting $_SESSION['myusername'] ?

Comment: You should be hashing (sha1 or stronger) the password when you save it to the DB and checking for that value in the DB, not storing a plaintext password and checking for the plaintext version. If you do that, you do not need to escape the password string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `session_start();` in first file

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="david_bpd"; // Mysql username
```

Comment: $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

Comment: myusername is checked against a mysql database in the first script

Comment: ok so do this before refresh <?php die($_SESSION['myusername']." vs ".$myusername); ?> what does it return?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: myusername in /home/david/public_html/bowlplexdoubles/index.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: myusername in /home/david/public_html/bowlplexdoubles/index.php on line 13

Comment: before the redirects in the second file

Comment: I got it. You forgot to session_start();

Comment: after `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";` put `echo $sql;die();` and put reponse here

Comment: SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='john' and password='1234'

Comment: and now, execute this in phpMyAdmin - will you get any result?

Comment: Ok. try to add `echo $count;die();` after `$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
` and delete that `echo $sql;die();`

Comment: when i do the debugging suggested above I get this

array(1) { ["myusername"]=> string(13) "administrator" } NULL Session has User-Name?: 1
User is logged in?::0
?>

?

Comment: is $myusername defined there: `if ($_SESSION['myusername'] == $myusername) {
//User should be allowed to be on page
}` ???

Comment: i don't think so but i don't know how to because it comes from a $_POST on a differnt page source code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398603/php-login-system-session-register-and-session-start-errors

Comment: Guys, this is not a chat room or IM. You've now posted more than 20 comments back and forth. @David, edit your original question if you need to provide more information. @genesis, edit your answer if you need to provide more details. This "conversation" is causing your answer to be flagged for moderator attention, and may result in it being locked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call session_start() **before** you set $_SESSION['myusername']

Comment: sorry. It was horrible mistake, nothing against you!

Comment: no worries for me :)
Just some explanation on the case: When you set $_SESSION[any_var] without starting session_start() first, there is no cookie set on the system which allows PHP to identify the real session.
The session is usually named PHPSESSID and will expire on closing the browser..

So, when no session_start() called first, there is no cookie to identify..

Answer (score 0):

Probably debugging helps:

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION, $myusername); // The second one should be unset in your case you need to fix this!

$sessionHasUserName = isset($_SESSION['myusername']);
$userIsLoggedIn = $sessionHasUserName && $_SESSION['myusername'] == $myusername;

printf('<b>Session has User-Name?:</b> %d<br /><b>User is logged in?:</b>:%d<br />', $sessionHasUserName, $userIsLoggedIn);

if ($userIsLoggedIn)
{
  //User should be allowed to be on page
} else {
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=index">';
}

?>
```

Comment: array(1) { ["myusername"]=> string(13) "administrator" } NULL Session has User-Name?: 1
User is logged in?::0
?>

Comment: So you're not logged in. This is because `$myusername` is an empty variable. As genesis wrote, you need to set it first!